# Video playback RAM/CPU issue

Tags: video, memory, cpu, overheating, 1080p

I have a 6 GB 1080p video file,as soon as i start playing it on different players including VLC,MPC HT e.t.c. 6G RAM shoots upto 90% usage and the CPU i7 950 3.0 GHz heats up to 80d ,now i have another 1080p with around 17 GB in size and it plays fine.

Can somebody help.

Comment: The container/codec formats, audio/video bitrates, and many other encoding parameters *might* explain the difference, although going by your PC specs it *should* have no problem handling both. Check that the first file is not corrupted, try remuxing (not re-encoding) it before playback, and try something like [PotPlayer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/PotPlayer) instead. Also, do provide further details about the files.

Comment: @Karan's comment should be an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

(Posting as answer as per suggestion)

The container/codec formats, audio/video bitrates, and many other encoding parameters might explain the difference, although going by your PC specs it should have no problem handling both. Check that the first file is not corrupted, try remuxing (not re-encoding) it before playback, and try something like [PotPlayer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/PotPlayer) instead.

Also, do provide further details about the files ([MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download) can help with this).